# How to pass values to defined template from views.py in Django-python

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a model like this:

```
class EventTypeCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="Name")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="User")
    Message_slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, verbose_name="Message")

       def __unicode__(self):
           return self.name
```

In urls.py:

```
url(r'^categ/$',
    'eventcateg_detail', name='eventcateg_detail'),
```

In views.py:

```
def eventcateg_detail(request,event_categ_id=None, event_categ_slug=None):
```

I want to add/edit/delete(CRUD) above defined value i.e name and Message_slug by template level. I am not getting any hint how to relate url.py with views.py and what should be definition of eventcateg_detail function.How this function will pass values to template (template name will be categ.html)

I am newbie in Django :)
want your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow the URL to accept parameters to allow you specify which event category you want to view:

```
/categ/outdoor-events/
/categ/catered-events/ 
...
```

Do do this, you use [a named URL pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in your url scheme:

```
url(r'^categ/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$','eventcateg_detail', name='eventcateg_detail'),
```

and in your view:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
def eventcateg_detail(request,slug):
    return render(request, "categ.html", {
        'obj' : get_object_or_404(EventCateg, Message_slug =slug) # You should change Message_slug to just slug
    })
```

and in your template:

```
<h1>{{ obj.name }}</h1>
```

So when a user enters a URL like we have outlined above, it gets matched to our URL pattern and the slug part of the url (`catered-events`) gets passed as a parameter to our view.

Comment: It shows obj is not globally defined and i have a doubt if i also want to print message slug in template then it should be obj.slug or something other?

Comment: There was a typo inside the `render` function of the view - notice that it is `'obj'` and not `obj` (braces around the name). You will use `obj.Message_slug` as that's how you have definied the slug field in your `EventCateg` model (this is bad practice - you should rename the field simply `slug')

Answer (score 2):

It's better that you follow the Django tutorial first, this is all covered in there. See for example [part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/) of the tutorial for more information on how to relate urls.py with views.py and [part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial04/) discusses passing variables to the template.

Comment: Also the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/) is very useful for the basics although it is getting a little old now

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I *believe* that a view function is only passed an httprequest when it is called by the Django framework, the other two parameters of the function will only be useful if you call the function yourself but will not be useful *through the web*.</strike>

As pointed out in the comments I was mistaken in my belief, extra parameters can be passed as dynamic urls (i.e. urls designated like this  `url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail')`,. See this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/?from=olddocs) and the answer by @pastylegs

The [Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) will allow you to edit all model fields if this is what you are after. Instructions on setting it up can be found in the Django documentation.

However I think what you are asking is how to enable CRUD editing through the web to users who are not admin level users. In that case you have many options. One of those options is to use a pre-built framework for Django like [piston](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-piston/en/latest/#fully-functional-example). Another way would be to use [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#create-update-delete-generic-views)

The other option is to build views yourself enabling operations on your model. In that case all of Django is available to you. You can pass parameters to your custom functions *within* the httprequest, for example as POST data.

Comment: `the other two parameters of the function will only be useful if you call the function yourself but will not be useful through the web.` the other two parameters are used by named parameters when you are [calling a dynamic url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#example), nothing to do with calling the view yourself

Comment: This answer is misleading. Django Piston is aimed at creating REST Apis and hasn't much to do with CRUD except that you can expose a CRUD API to devices and clients. Regarding POSTing, this again hasn't much do to with CRUD except that it is how you will transmit your data. If you want CRUD look into simply using the django admin or implemented it yourself with [generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/generic-views/#create-update-delete-generic-views) (There's a whole section dedicated to it)

Comment: Thank you for educating me :), I updated my answer to reflect your points.